# leaflet js: draw POIs as canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geojson, leaflet

I want to draw many geo points with Leaflet. Therefore I want to use HTML5 canvas to improve the performance.
My datasoure is geoJSON. As I saw in the documention of Leaflet, it is not possible to draw the geo positions as canvas yet.

```
var anotherGeojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(coorsField, {
        pointToLayer: function (latlng){
            return new L.Marker(latlng, {
                icon: new BaseballIcon()
            });
        }
    });
```

I think I should hook up here:

> pointToLayer: function (latlng) { }

Does somebody know how to draw my latlng objects as canvas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm Leaflet author. You can do this by using L.CircleMarker instead of regular Marker, and also using an experimental L_PREFER_CANVAS switch to render vectors as Canvas (instead of SVG), like this: https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/blob/master/debug/vector/vector-canvas.html

Comment: A lot of time has passed since this. Do you have any new information that you can share for how to do this in newer versions?

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on the original answer in case anyone needs this for Leaflet 1.0.  You should still use `L.circleMarker()` [(Leaflet circleMarker documentation)](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#circlemarker) instead of `L.marker()`, but the way to use the canvas has changed.

In Leaflet 1.0, the experimental `L_PREFER_CANVAS` switch has been upgraded to an official map option `preferCanvas` [(Leaflet preferCanvas documentation)](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-prefercanvas).

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {
        preferCanvas: true
    });
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly set the canvas renderer; I think this does the same thing as the `preferCavas` option.  Here's the [Leaflet documentation for canvas](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#canvas).

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {
        renderer: L.canvas()
    });
```

Either of these options (`preferCanvas: true` or `renderer: L.canvas()`) with `L.circleMarker()` was significantly faster than a regular layer using `L.marker()`.

Comment: A lot of time has passed since this. Do you have any new information that you can share for how to do this in newer versions?