# Ionic Angular Leaflet - performant rendering of many svg markers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I want to render many custom (svg) markers on my map. After my initial research I found a couple of approaches, but none of these seem to be applicable in my case. I'm using `ionic/angular 5.0.0` and leaflet `1.7.1`.

This is what I have:

```
displayMarkers(foos: Foo[]) {
    // Transform foos into clickable markers
    this.markers = foos.map((foo) => {
        const i = icon({
            iconUrl: '/assets/img/icon.svg', // I'd like to use this svg for my markers
            iconSize: [20, 20], // size of the icon
        });
        const marker = circleMarker([foo.lat, foo.long]); // ADD ICON HERE

        return marker.on('click', () => this.onSelectMarker(foo, marker));
    });
    // Filter markers only in bounds of the map
    this.markers = this.markers.filter(m => this.map.getBounds().contains(m.getLatLng()));
    // Draw the markers onto the map
    this.markers.forEach(marker=> marker.addTo(this.map));
}
```

I'd like to replace or customize the `leaflet circleMarker` with my `svg` or find a performant way to render a lot of svg elements in my map (thousands).

I know, I could use `markers` to display `svg icons`, however the performance of the application will suffer immensely, once you hit a few hundred markers.

I'd like to have the option to initialize the map like so:

```
new Map('mapId', {preferCanvas: true})
```

or be able to use a custom renderer, like so:

```
const marker = circleMarker([foo.lat, foo.long], {renderer: canvas()});
```

That way, the markers will be drawn onto the canvas and not be treated as single DOM-Elements.

I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850249/leaflet-js-too-slow-with-custom-svg-markers-and-a-lot-of-points) solution, but I was unable to integrate it in my angular-typescript application properly.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487771/use-custom-icons-with-canvas-rendering-leaflet) question and installed and tested all the suggested libraries. However the question was too open and the libraries weren't satisfying to me and seemed to only serve a minimalistic purpose. Maybe I'm just to dumb to integrate them properly (I don't want to loose the benefits of angular and typescript, though)...

I feel like there has to be a simple solution here, but I cannot seem to find it. Am I missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after many hours of trial and error, I eventually figured it out. I used and changed the code from several answers and examples to fit my specific use case. So if anyone is curious to what I did, here it goes...

I put all my code into one file for your convenience.

`map.page.ts`:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-map',
templateUrl: './map.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./map.page.scss'],
})
export class MapPage implements OnInit {
    map: Map; // Leaflet map
    userLocation: Marker; // Leaflet marker
    foos$: Observable<Foo[]>; // Your data
    // Some other variables ...

    constructor(
        private geocoder: NativeGeocoder,
        private fooStore: Store<fromFoo.FooState>,
        //... 
    ) {}

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.map = this.getInitialMap(); // Init map
        this.fooStore.dispatch(...); // Load foos to display
        this.foos$ = this.fooStore.pipe(select(fromFoo.getFoos));
        this.foos$.subscribe(foos => {
            if (foos && foos.length > 0) {
                this.displayFoos(foos);
            }
        });
        // Some more stuff here...
    }

    getInitialMap() {
        const layer = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 19
        });
        return new Map('mapId', {
            zoomControl: !Browser.mobile,
            layers: [layer],
            center: [???, ???], // Define arbitrary location
            zoom: 19,
        });
    }

   
    displayFoos(foos: Foo[]) {
        const renderer = new Canvas(); // Important! use a canvas to render your data
        // Map the foos (your data) to leaflet markers
        const fooMarkers = foos.map((foo) => 
              new CustomMarker([foo.lat, foo.long], {renderer})
        ); // Note the CustomMarker here (See below for implementation)
        // Draw the markers onto the map
        fooMarkers.forEach(fooMarker => fooMarker.addTo(this.map));
    }

    // More functions here...
}

// This is important!
// Create a class for your custom markers that extend the CircleMarker from Leaflet
class CustomMarker extends CircleMarker {
    _updatePath() { // Make sure to name it "_updatePath()"
        // @ts-ignore
        this._renderer._displayCustomSVG(this); // Call the _renderer, which
        // to my understanding is a property on a circle marker that
        // refers to a canvas. You can extend the Canvas by your 
        // own custom render function (see below)
    }
}

const imageBitmap = new Image(); // Create a bitmap. Found on another answer
// I defined the new image outside the _displayCustomSVG to increase performance.
// That way the image instance is only created once, rather than foo.length times.

// Include ("extend") the leaflet canvas by your custom render function
Canvas.include({
    _displayCustomSVG(layer) {
        if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) {
            return;
        }
        const p = layer._point;
        // Insert your own svg as string. (I stripped the svg here)
        const svgStr = `<svg width="10px" height="10px" viewBox="0.0 0.0 100.0 113.75853018372703" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>`;
        // (I used an online editor to upload my svg and turn it
        // into an svg string.)
        // You might want to change the width or height of your svg
  
        imageBitmap.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgStr);

        const ctx = this._ctx;
        imageBitmap.onload = ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, p.x, p.y);
    },
});
```

This is the result:
[image]

This works for me, however I don't know if there's a more performant or better way of doing this. Anyway, I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I realized that if you put the `const imageBitmap = new Image();` outside the `_displayCustomSVG()` you could run into some inconsistencies with the `drawImage` function from leaflet.